# How to make work the jquery nested tab link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, tabs, nested

I am having problem with Jquery tabs UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs').tabs();
    $('.subtabs').tabs();
});

<div class="tabs">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
   </ul>
       <div id="tab1">
            <div class="subtabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#subtab1">Subtab1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#subtab2">Subtab2</a></li>
                </ul>
            <div id="subtab1">
                 Some content1
            </div>
            <div id="subtab2">
                 Some content2
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
       <div id="tab2"></div>
</div>
```

Now when i try to access subtab like page.html#subtab1 it does not work, 
but page.html#tab1 works. What am i doing wrong? basically i need to open subtab using URL.

Thanks

Comment: Try `$('.tabs, .subtabs').tabs();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `<div id="tab2"></div>` which will give a jQuery exception.
Try adding that to the code and your links will work.

Comment: I have this tag <div id="tab2"></div> in my code, still does not work.

Comment: The tabs looks good, but when i want to go to the tab with direct url,like www.site.com/page.html#subtab2, it does not work, the first tab just opens instead.

Comment: I've tested it and it works in FF. What browser are you using? What version of jQuery UI are you using? Clear cache and refresh your page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And I found a JS fix for it. Please note that in your example you had the subtabs in the first tab, the first tab is the default tab that opens. With my fix you can place the subtabs inside any content of the main tab. Check the Plunker for the working example.

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Wr91Bm/#subtab2

I created the function `openParentTab()` and called this right after I created the `$('.tabs, .subtabs').tabs();`

```
function openParentTab() {
    locationHash = location.hash.substring( 1 );
    console.log(locationHash);
    // Check if we have an location Hash
    if (locationHash) {
        // Check if the location hash exsist.
        var hash = jQuery('#'+locationHash);
        if (hash.length) {
            // Check of the location Hash is inside a tab.
            if (hash.closest(".tabContent").length) {
                // Grab the index number of the parent tab so we can activate it
                var tabNumber = hash.closest(".tabContent").index();
                jQuery(".tabs.fix").tabs({ active: tabNumber });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an big page and you find the focus isnt on the correct subtab you can add the following below `jQuery(".tabs.fix").tabs({ active: tabNumber });`

```
hash.get(0).scrollIntoView();
setTimeout(function() {
    hash.get(0).scrollIntoView();
}, 1000);
```

See code: http://plnkr.co/Wr91Bm