# Jquery open sub-tabs (nest-tabs) by link

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have main tabs and sub-tabs, my question is how to access sub-tab by direct link.

Example: mypage.html#subtab2

default we can access main tabs only.

mypage.html#tab2 is working..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tabs').tabs();
      $('.subtabs').tabs();
    });

   <div class="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
   <div id="tab1">
        <div class="subtabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#subtab1">Subtab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#subtab2">Subtab2</a></li>
            </ul>
        <div id="subtab1">
             Some content1
        </div>
        <div id="subtab2">
             Some content2
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
   <div id="tab2"></div>
```

I search a similar my question at but not found correct answer, now i re-post.

[How to make work the jquery nested tab link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976219/how-to-make-work-the-jquery-nested-tab-link)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make work the jquery nested tab link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976219/how-to-make-work-the-jquery-nested-tab-link)

Answer (score 0):

As I also posted here [How to make work the jquery nested tab link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976219/how-to-make-work-the-jquery-nested-tab-link) this is my answer/fix for the problem:

I had the same problem. And I found a JS fix for it. Please note that in your example you had the subtabs in the first tab, the first tab is the default tab that opens. With my fix you can place the subtabs inside any content of the main tab. Check the Plunker for the working example.

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Wr91Bm/#subtab2

I created the function `openParentTab()` and called this right after I created the `$('.tabs, .subtabs').tabs();`

```
function openParentTab() {
    locationHash = location.hash.substring( 1 );
    console.log(locationHash);
    // Check if we have an location Hash
    if (locationHash) {
        // Check if the location hash exsist.
        var hash = jQuery('#'+locationHash);
        if (hash.length) {
            // Check of the location Hash is inside a tab.
            if (hash.closest(".tabContent").length) {
                // Grab the index number of the parent tab so we can activate it
                var tabNumber = hash.closest(".tabContent").index();
                jQuery(".tabs.fix").tabs({ active: tabNumber });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an big page and you find the focus isnt on the correct subtab you can add the following below `jQuery(".tabs.fix").tabs({ active: tabNumber });`

```
hash.get(0).scrollIntoView();
setTimeout(function() {
    hash.get(0).scrollIntoView();
}, 1000);
```

See code: http://plnkr.co/Wr91Bm